# Multiple tabs on same session scoped bean are interfering each other

Tags: jsf

I have JSF 2.0 e-commerce application. I'm using 2 session scoped beans: ProductBean and CartBean.
ProductBean holds Product entity representing current product user is viewing. CartBean holds list of Products.
CartBean has method addProduct(Product p). I have problem with adding to cart when using multiple tabs. Here's scenario:

> 1. User visits product page: /product?id=111
> 2. User opens new browser tab for another product: /product?id=222
> 3. User goes back to first tab and clicks 'add to cart' - Second product (id=222) is added to cart.

Here's the code of add to cart commandButton action:

```
#{cartBean.addProduct(productBean.product)}
```

It's clear to me what's going on. How can I make this work on multiple tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `ProductBean` [request](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/girch.html)-scoped. If your beans are session-scoped they're global to all requests. Similarly, if they're application-scoped, they're global to all sessions.

Comment: CartBean is not needed to be request scoped. Only the ProductBean needs request scope.

Comment: Note that the old Java EE 5 tutorial where you're linking to handles old JSF 1.2. OP is using JSF 2.0 wherein you can just use annotations on the class instead of the verbose faces-config.xml. You seem to not really ever have used JSF, is it?

Comment: @BalusC: How would I know about request scopes if I've never used Java EE? I'm aware of annotation-based properties. My only intent was to provide a resource the OP could look at for a review of scoping. Thanks for the heads up on using the old tutorial though. Updated.